# Why bootstrap navbar dropdown doesn't move content below when i change Navbar height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have `navbar` which when i click icon move content below and it working perfectly but when i want to change `CSS` height i'm facing with a problem(drop down just overlapping `h3` text instead of moving down).

Here is working fiddle:-

With height( https://jsfiddle.net/kds8pe0L/6/) Working correctly

Witouth height ( https://jsfiddle.net/hkeo7fg9/) Here is mistake

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Master thesis application</title>

   <!-- Jquery --> 


  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
<!-- Import css file-->




 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>




  </head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
  <body>


<nav class="navbar  navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>


        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->



               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="/home">Clients</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/charts">Charts</a></li>

               </ul>


            @if (Sentinel::guest())
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

               <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

               </ul>

            @endif   
       @if(!Sentinel::guest())
         @if(Sentinel::inRole('admin'))
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            Admin Panel  <span class="caret"></span>  </a>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="/adminsProfiles">Admins List</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/viewersProfiles">Users List</a></li>
                  </ul>

                 </li>

            </ul>
          @endif
        @endif

       @if(!Sentinel::guest())
          @if(Sentinel::inRole('viewer'))
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">       
            <li> <a href="{{ route('profile', ['first_name' => Sentinel::getUser()->first_name]) }}">Profile</a></li>

            </ul>
           @endif
       @endif

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @if (Sentinel::guest())
                    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
                @else
                         <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{Sentinel::getUser()->first_name}}  <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ URL::to('/logout') }}"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                              document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    Logout
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ URL::to('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>



<h2 class="text-center" >List of clients</h2>

    <div class="container">

    </div> <!-- /container -->



  </body>
</html>
```

Css

```
  body {

background-image: url("/images/images.jpg"); 

}
  .container {
            max-width: 940px;
        }
#header{
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #007ab3;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 100px;


}

.navbar {
    position: relative;

    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent; 
     border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-inverse{

    background-color: #004666;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
}}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
}
.nav>li>a {
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: white;

}

.tablica{

    float:left;
}
td{
  text-align: center;  
  width: 10%;
}

th{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.table {
    width: 90%;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #004666;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
}

th{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: My mistake sorry, try now

Comment: which height you are changing and causing the issue?

Comment: Navbar height..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `min-height: 30px;` and not `height: 30px;`, the nav bar will grow as you expect.

https://jsfiddle.net/hkeo7fg9/5/

```css
  body {

background-image: url("/images/images.jpg"); 

}
  .container {
            max-width: 940px;
        }
#header{
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #007ab3;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 100px;


}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent; 
     border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-inverse{

    background-color: #004666;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
}}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
}
.nav>li>a {
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: white;

}

.tablica{

    float:left;
}
td{
  text-align: center;  
  width: 10%;
}

th{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.table {
    width: 90%;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #004666;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
}

th{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Master thesis application</title>

   <!-- Jquery --> 

    
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/jumbotron-narrow/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<!-- Import css file-->

<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<!-- Highcharts for normal chart


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

-->

<!-- Highcharts for normal tockSchart -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


  </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
</script>
  <body>
  

<nav class="navbar  navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->


              @if (!Sentinel::guest())
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="/home">Clients</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/charts">Charts</a></li>

               </ul>

            @endif  
            @if (Sentinel::guest())
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

               <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

               </ul>

            @endif   
       @if(!Sentinel::guest())
         @if(Sentinel::inRole('admin'))
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            Admin Panel  <span class="caret"></span>  </a>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="/adminsProfiles">Admins List</a></li>
           
                        <li><a href="/viewersProfiles">Users List</a></li>
                  </ul>
                     
                 </li>

            </ul>
          @endif
        @endif

       @if(!Sentinel::guest())
          @if(Sentinel::inRole('viewer'))
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">       
            <li> <a href="{{ route('profile', ['first_name' => Sentinel::getUser()->first_name]) }}">Profile</a></li>

            </ul>
           @endif
       @endif

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @if (Sentinel::guest())
                    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
                @else
                         <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{Sentinel::getUser()->first_name}}  <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ URL::to('/logout') }}"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                              document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    Logout
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ URL::to('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>



<h2 class="text-center" >List of clients</h2>

    <div class="container">
  
    </div> <!-- /container -->


 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool beans. I use min-height often because you can give it that minimum width, but it can expand if needed. Feel free to mark as correct for future users.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the `.navbar-header` class if you want to resize the bar.

For example:

```
.navbar-header {
   height: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p7mrq5v4/